# What range of emotions and sensory acuity do the Transformers exhibit?

Tags: transformers

Transformers possess superior Cognitive intelligence, they distinguish right from wrong which is why Optimus is dead set on protecting our young earth, however, are these dudes emotionally intelligent or aware? do they feel pain/love/sadness? can they even get high on "alcohol"(or gasoline)?
On the issue of pain for instance, an autobot would probably have to have some sort of nerve-network(similar to ours) running through its metallic frame to feel the sensation of losing a headlight.

Comment: I think it's fairly obvious from pretty much every Transformers story ever told that Transformers experience a full range of emotions, from anger and sadness to joy, that they have a sense of humor, that they feel pain.

Comment: Also, Transformers consuming substances in the same way that humans consume alcohol is a topic that's fairly well-documented - mostly in the comic books. That should probably be edited out of this question and posted as its own question, because it would be pretty easy to write a definitive answer to that.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much every incarnation of Transformers has evidence of all of the emotions you mentioned with the exception of physical pain (that I can recall). Here are some standouts off the top of my head.

**Gen 1**

- Love: in [The Girl Who Loved Powerglide](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/The_Girl_Who_Loved_Powerglide), Powerglide and Astoria fall in love. in [Sea Change](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/The_Girl_Who_Loved_Powerglide), Sea Spray and Alana fall in love. While not explicitly stated, it's also implied that Optimus/Orion Pax and Elita-1 were in love.
- Fear: in [Auto Berserk](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Auto_Berserk), Red Alert becomes paranoid that he is being replaced. Starscream frequently expresses fear that Megatron will destroy him.
- Sadness: All of the Autobots express sadness at Optimus' death in *Transformers: The Movie*

**Beast Wars/Machines**

- Love: Silverbolt repeatedly expresses his love for Blackarachnia.
- Sadness: Optimus Primal expresses sadness at the revelation of Tankor's identity.

**Transformers Prime**

- Fear:  In [Scrapheap](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Scrapheap_%28episode%29), Bulkhead expresses explicit fear of the Scraplets, even screaming "like a little girl".
- Sadness: All of the Autobots express sadness at the presumed death of Optimus.

**Live-Action**

- Fear: In *Dark of the Moon*, Bumblebee expresses fear when he is held at gunpoint by Soundwave. In *Age of Extinction*, Ratched expresses fear when he is held at gunpoint by Lockdown.
- Sadness: Optimus expresses sadness at the death of *Jazz* in the original movie. All of the Autobots express sadness at the death of Optimus in *Revenge of the Fallen*.